# Browser displays "Upgrade Required" when running this program

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, websocket

So I searched for a week now, tried every solution in other Posts or Forums, still nothing so yeah I'm in need of help .. please.

Node is up to date, if thats important. FYI. v9.4.0

If there's something else you guys need to know let me know.

```
'use strict'

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
var util = require('util')

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server

var CONNECTION_ERROR_LOG_RATE = 1000 * 60 * 60

var Browser = function () {
  if (!(this instanceof Browser)) return new Browser()
  EventEmitter.call(this)
  this.wss = null
  this.ws = null
  this.lastConnectionErrorLog = null
}

util.inherits(Browser, EventEmitter)

Browser.prototype.listen = function listen (port) {
  console.log('Listening on websocket port %d', port)
  this.wss = new WebSocketServer({port, host: '127.0.0.1'})

  var self = this
  this.wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    self.ws = ws

    ws.on('message', function (data) {
      var res = JSON.parse(data)
      self.emit('message', res)
    })
    self.lastConnectionErrorLog = null
    self.emit('connected')
  })
  this.wss.on('close', function () {
    self.emit('closed')
  })
  this.wss.on('error', function (err) {
    self.emit('error', err)
  })
}

Browser.prototype.isConnected = function isConnected () {
  return !!this.ws
}

Browser.prototype.send = function send (req) {
  if (!this.ws) {
    var elapsed = this.lastConnectionErrorLog === null ||
      Date.now() - this.lastConnectionErrorLog > CONNECTION_ERROR_LOG_RATE
    if (elapsed) {
      console.log('browser not connected')
      this.lastConnectionErrorLog = Date.now()
    }
    return
  }

  var self = this
  var message = JSON.stringify(req)
  this.ws.send(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      var elapsed = self.lastConnectionErrorLog === null ||
        Date.now() - self.lastConnectionErrorLog > CONNECTION_ERROR_LOG_RATE
      if (elapsed) {
        self.lastConnectionErrorLog = Date.now()
        self.emit('messageError', err)
      }
    } else {
      self.emit('messageSent')
    }
  })
}

module.exports = Browser
```

I am kind of new to Websockets/Node/Javascript so it may be that the answer is very simple.. 
I apologize in advance
Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because you are sending a non-WebSocket request (i.e, a normal HTTP request from a web browser) to a WebSockets server.

To connect to a WebSockets server in a browser, you'll need to use the `WebSocket` interface in Javascript.

Comment: How exactly? I'm using WS as a NodeModule which handles WebSockets

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted doesn't include the string "Upgrade required" so the problem must be coming from elsewhere.  Since you're working with Node/NPM, it's usually pretty easy to figure out where this problem *is* coming from.  Just use your IDE to search across all files in your project director (including the node_modules folder) to see where the "Upgrade required" string is found.  This will at least point you to which component is triggering that error and point you towards where to look for further troubleshooting and/or upgrading.